# Bottom overflowed by 182 pixels

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add textfields in a widget on Flutter, and it renders correctly, but when the text is pressed to enter the data, appears the following error:

"Bottom overflowed by 182 pixels"

The error is when the default keyboard appears. I don't know why is it happening since i am wrapping everything in a SingleChildScrollView widget, therefore, should work just fine.

Attached the code:

```
class TextFieldsState extends State<TextFields> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const colorRed = Color(0xFFF0786E);
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: 20.0,
          vertical: 20.0,
        ),
        //color: Colors.greenAccent,
        height: 500,
        child: Stack(
          //alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container (
              height: 500,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                color: colorRed,
              ),
              child: Container (
                height: 500,
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10,),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Positioned (
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 136,
                  //width: size.width,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 160,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Name',
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 160,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Surname',
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 20.0),

                      Container(
                        height: 30,
                        width: 160,
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Nationality',
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,

                        ),
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What is the solution, please?

Comment: please check the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up wrapping everything with a Expanded widget and the column with the Text fields I wrapped it with a SingleChilsScrollView and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

try this please

```
SingleChildScrollView(
   column(  // your column
   )
)
```

overflow error is in column and you should add `SingleChildScrollView` as parent of this column.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the edited below code.

```
class TextFieldsState extends State<TextFields> {

    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      const colorRed = Color(0xFFF0786E);
      return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 20.0,
            vertical: 20.0,
          ),
          //color: Colors.greenAccent,
          height: 500,
          child: Stack(
            //alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 500,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22.0),
                  color: colorRed,
                ),
                child: Container(
                  height: 500,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                    right: 10,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 136,
                  //width: size.width,
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 160,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Name',
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 160,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Surname',
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                        Container(
                          height: 30,
                          width: 160,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.blue,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              ),
                              hintText: 'Nationality',
                            ),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```